# Laravel mix: how to execute a PHP Lint?

Tags: laravel-5.4, laravel-mix

Prologue: I'm playing for the first time with Laravel.

I'd like to use the 'laravel-mix' to run a php lint on my php files when file changes.

Is this doable?

I looked at official doc about Laravel-mix but I found no examples about PHP files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I understand that It's not possible.

Laravel right tool is Envoy. I created Enojy tasks/stories and all now can run well